# Transcoding via FFmpeg. Set starting pcr value

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, transcoding, mpeg2-ts

I transcoding via FFmpeg (video codec - h264, container - MPEG-TS) output writing to local file (out.mpg). When FFmpeg dropped I restarted it with output to the same file (out.mpg). After this my video player shows incorrect file duration due to new FFmpeg process start counting PCR from 0. 
**Can I set starting pcr value at start FFmpeg ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run FFmpeg with key **-copyts** solved this issue.